# Python libtorrent

Tags: python, windows-7, libtorrent

I have installed python libtorrent on my Windows 7 machine using the .msi installer. When I do import libtorrent I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x:\Dropbox\PyDVR\torrent.py", line 3, in <module>
    import libtorrent as lt
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The code that you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be due to the architecture of your OS. Check if your OS is 64 bit and you are running Python 64bit. If not try to match them and the problem might be solved. And also check if your libtorrent is 64/32 bit as appropriate. If your OS and python are 64 bit and you are using 32 bit libtorrent, this issue can occur.

Comment: I am running Windows 7 64-bit and Python 64-bit:
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75708, Oct 26 2009, 07:36:50) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
The python libtorrent is only available as win32 here:
[link](https://code.google.com/p/libtorrent/downloads/list)

Comment: is your libtorrent 64 bit binary?

Comment: I installed Python 2.7 32-bit and libtorrent for python 2.7 and this worked.

Comment: I've noticed a lot of python libraries only work in 32-bit mode as well.